# How can the limit of convergence of a binomial series of the function $(1+x)^p$ be $|x|<1$?

Tags: convergence-divergence

For a function $(1+x)^p$, when we write the power series and use the ratio test to find out the interval of convergence, we get $|x|<1$. But take a positive value of $p$, 3 for example. The function becomes $(1+x)^3$ and surely the power series reduces to $1+3x+3x^2+x^3$, and This gives a finite value for any value of $x$ not just for $|x|<1$, so what is it that I'm missing ?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Math Stack Exchange. Please edit your post, using math formattation because this is unreadable. Thanks.

Comment: The convergence of the power series is from the center to the nearest singularity. $(1+x)^p=\exp(p\ln(1+x))$. The $\ln(1+x)$ has a singularity at $x=-1$ and most of the time multiplying by $p$ and taking $\exp$ doesn't remove it. But as you saw, for $p\in\mathbb{N}$ it does. The most clear reason of how it gets removed I think it is the computation that you did of showing that the function coincides with a polynomial.

Comment: You should write the derivation that you say gives $|x|<1$. Then we can tell you what step changes if $p$ is a natural number.

Comment: Your caveat applies for p a positive integer, where we have an ordinary polynomial.    Fractional or negative p are different stories.

Comment: If $p$ is a positive integer the coefficients in the power series at hand will be zero eventually, hence the ratio test will be quite problematic..!